# How to install ferret gem on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ferret

I was trying to run an OpenSource project which requires ferret to be installed. While installing it using gem install ferret, it's giving this error ->

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing ferret:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>   creating Makefile
>
> nmake 'nmake' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ferret-0.11.6
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ferret-0.11.6/ext/gem_make.out

So, I tried installing nmake (nmake15.exe), but I couldn't find it. It does not install on Windows 7.  How can I install ferret?

Comment: did you ever find an answer?  i'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Some Ruby gems use native extensions, which means they're partially written in C or C++. These gems need to be compiled during installation, which is easy if you're on Linux. Also, most of these gems provide binaries for Windows. However, some gems, like ferret's, don't and still need to be compiled during installation.

The good news is that a toolkit called DevKit makes it easy to build native extensions on Windows. Follow the installation guide here: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Answer (score 0):

`nmake` is similiar to the `make` Unix tool used for compiling C and other languages. Some Ruby extensions that use C code need to be compiled.

nmake comes with Visual Studio (C++, C#, and VB). Alternatively, download [nmake.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/vc15/Patch/1.52/W95/EN-US/Nmake15.exe) by itself. Install either and your problem should clear up.

Answer (score 0):

Execute Below command and its works

gem install ferret --platform=mswin32

Comment: @BrettVeenstra : what window version do you have?